# Opencv C++ ; Display Multiple images using int in titles

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to display multiple images and I want different titles that has int value comes from for loop. I mean I cannot do this:

```
  int i = 7;

  Mat result;

 imshow("Result with Gaussian Filter &d X &d", i, i, result);
```

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: `imshow` is not a `printf`-like function. If you want to have runtime-determined ints in your image title I'm afraid you'll have to `sprintf()` to a char buffer, or make a `stringstream`.

Comment: DO NOT abuse the window title for temporary /changing information. other functions like imshow, createTrachbar, etc., depend on it as a  key.

Comment: @berak that's interesting. Can you provide some details? Or some source that does?

Comment: easy, namedWindow("title1"); imshow("title2");  // will open a 2nd window.

Comment: @berak I meant how do (and what) other functions depend on window title as a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
cv::Mat result;

char windowName[10];
sprintf(windowName, "%d X %d", i, i);
cv::imshow(windowName, result);
```

or

```
cv::Mat result;

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << i << " X " << i;
std::string windowName = oss.str();
cv::imshow(windowName, result);
```